# Bash variable from subshell not storing return value from grep

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following line of code in a bash script:

```
# Is there an external monitor connected via HDMI?
has_external=$(xrandr 2> /dev/null | grep -q 'HDMI[0-9] connected')
```

The output of `xrandr` could contain this:

```
HDMI1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

For the life of my I can't figure out why the `has_external` variable always evaluates to true, even if "HDMI1 connected" is not in the output of `xrandr`. Any ideas?

Comment: Command substitution stores **output**, not exit status. `-q` suppresses output.

Comment: thus, `has_external` will always have the same empty value after the code in question has run. I would appreciate it if you could edit your question to show how you're determining it to "evaluate to true".

Comment: ... and consequently you probably wanted `xrandr 2> /dev/null | grep -q 'HDMI[0-9] connected'; has_external=$?`?

Comment: Brilliant, thanks @CharlesDuffy and dhke -- I assumed the exit status was stored in the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how you evaluate the variable `has_external` that it happens to be "always true" - that's probably the source of your problem.

You can do the same check with a condition like:

```
if xrandr 2> /dev/null | grep -q 'HDMI[0-9] connected'; then
   # HDMI present
fi
```

Or:

```
xrandr 2> /dev/null | grep -q 'HDMI[0-9] connected'
rc=$?
if [[ $rc == 0 ]]; then
    # HDMI present
fi
```

Comment: I'd suggest `(( rc == 0 ))` if you want bash-only syntax, or `[ "$rc" -eq 0 ]` otherwise. Also, as a best practice, appending `...; rc=$?` on the same line whose exit status you're capturing prevents additional logging or other changes from disrupting that exit status before it's captured if the folks making those edits aren't paying enough attention to context to notice the strict ordering dependency.